# Cant find a way to compare array keys

Tags: php, arrays

I've got these two arrays:

```
Array ONE
(
    [39] => Dude, Harry [10%]
    [36] => Occonell, Tim [90%]
)

Array TWO
(
    [1] => Person, Admin
    [2] => Snow, John
    [3] => Jane, Marry
    [14] => Kelchenko, Igory
    [18] => Bery, Grass
    [36] => Occonell, Tim
)
```

I'm trying to delete value from second array, if it's key is equal to first one. So my array should look like:

```
Array TWO
(
    [1] => Person, Admin
    [2] => Snow, John
    [3] => Jane, Marry
    [14] => Kelchenko, Igory
    [18] => Bery, Grass
)
```

I have attempted to find an answer else where, but I could not find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_diff()` is in the right direction, but you want to do stuff with the keys of the arrays, so use: [`array_diff_key()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php), e.g.

```
print_r(array_diff_key($array2, $array1));
```

As an example:

```
$array2 = [
    1 => "a",
    2 => "b",
    3 => "c",
    4 => "d",
    5 => "e",
]; 

$array1 = [
    2 => "Don't want this key",
    4 => "Also don't want this one",
];
```

output will be:

```
Array ( 
    1 => a
    3 => c
    5 => e
)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do following

```
foreach($arr_one as $key => $val){
    if(isset($array_2[$key]))    unset($array_2[$key]);
}
```